# Access a Computed Field in Views

Tags: views

I am trying to get the new version of Computed Fields to work on our site. It's working great, except I can't get it to be accessed in Views a field. In the README it explains that the new version has "computed field created by creating a computed field entity is always a bundle field, not a base field". Myself, and others, are talking to the module maintainer, but so far we haven't had much luck, so I thought I'd try here as well. Anyone have any idea how to access a bundle field as a regular field that can be used in Views.

Comment: I've never used the module, but I create custom computed view plugins, and I believe to use them in Views you need to implement `hook_views_data()`. Maybe the module does not do this automatically, and you need to implement it yourself in a module.

Comment: Computed bundle fields are not supported by Views. The corresponding issue is linked directly on the d.o module page itself. Example solution code needs 1 additional click: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2981047

Comment: I actually commented at drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2981047. The problem there is there were so many posts, I can't figure out if any of the patches will work on Drupal 9.5.x site. If so, which one?

Will hook_views_data() work on the new version bundle fields?